# Dialogflow: Is it possible to bypass the default reprompts if needed?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am developing an app with dialogflow and actions-on-google, using webhook and node.js to program intents.

My problem is that dialogflow gives default reprompts on intents as seen in the code below.

```
app.intent('Reprompt', (conv) => {
  const repromptCount = parseInt(conv.arguments.get('REPROMPT_COUNT'));
  if (repromptCount === 0) {
  conv.ask(`What was that?`);
  } else if (repromptCount === 1) {
  conv.ask(`Sorry I didn't catch that. Could you repeat yourself?`);
  } else if (conv.arguments.get('IS_FINAL_REPROMPT')) {
  conv.close(`Okay let's try this again later.`);
  }
});
```

The context is that I am programming a conversational agent that asks users questions such as "What made you smile today?" and I expect the users to talk about this question with their partner. The best case scenario is that the app asks the question and then only listens for "Next question" or "End conversation", but does not interrupt the users.

As for now, the default reprompt interrupts the users, saying "What was that?" after a bit of time.

Is it possible to fiddle with the reprompt so that it stops doing that?

I know that the reprompts is part of the 'Best practice' for developing conversational agents, but I this case it seems counter intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I ask users a few questions (survey), and whatever the answer is, I go to the next question. From my understanding, you are looking for something similar. Let's suppose you want to ask the user '*What's your name?*' and after they answer you want to ask them '*Where are you from?*'.Here's how you do it (maybe not the optimal way but it works): 
1. Create an intent 'name' and add a required parameter with prompt 'What is your name?'
2. Add a custom event 'userName' 
3. Enable webhook call for the fulfillment 
4. (Optional) You can add training phrases to invoke this intent 

Follow the same steps as above to create another intent for the country
1. Name intent 'country' and add a required parameter with prompt 'Where are you from?'
2. Add a custom event 'userCountry'
3. same as above

Now we will write a fulfillment function for 'name' intent that will trigger country question

```
function Name(agent){
    agent.add('This will invoke as respond to name question');
    agent.setFollowupEvent('userCountry');
}
```

So, what is happening is that when the user invokes intent *name* he has to tell his name and your bot doesn't respond but instead trigger *country* intent, where answering 'Where are you from?' is also required. So the final conversation will look as follow:

```
Bot: What is your name?
User: Blah Blah
Bot: Where you from?
User: Blah Blah
```